# Trouble with Get-WmiObject while running powershell script to back up DNS Zones

Tags: powershell

I have this script that I am trying to run, that I hope will back up DNS zones. I am attempting to export this information into a csv file using the export-csv powershell cmdlet. Finally, I use use the dnscmd.exe command to export zones information into a text file and store them in the defined location.

```
 # Get Name of the server with env variable
$DNSSERVER=get-content env:computername

#—Define folder where to store backup  —–#
$BkfFolder=”c:\windows\system32\dns\backup”

#—Define file name where to store Dns Settings
$StrFile=Join-Path $BkfFolder “input.csv”

#—-Check if folder exists. if exists, delete contents–#
if (-not(test-path $BkfFolder)) {
new-item $BkfFolder -Type Directory | Out-Null
} else {

Remove-Item $BkfFolder”\*” -recurse
}

#—- GET DNS SETTINGS USING WMI OBJECT ——–#
#– Line wrapped should be only one line –#
$List = get-WmiObject -ComputerName $DNSSERVER
-Namespace root\MicrosoftDNS -Class MicrosoftDNS_Zone

#—-Export information into input.csv file —#
#– Line wrapped should be only one line –#
$list | Select Name,ZoneType,AllowUpdate,@{Name=”MasterServers”;Expression={$_.MasterServers}},
DsIntegrated | Export-csv $strFile -NoTypeInformation

#— Call Dnscmd.exe to export dns zones
$list | foreach {
$path=”backup\”+$_.name
$cmd=”dnscmd {0} /ZoneExport {1} {2}” -f $DNSSERVER,$_.Name,$path
Invoke-Expression $cmd
}

# End of Script
#——————————————————————————————-#
```

When I run the script, I get the following message:

[image]

I am not exactly sure what this message is saying. I tried inputting my computer name, but that does not work either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Remove the line break before `-Namespace...`, so that all the arguments are on the same line

Comment: ..or add a space and a  backtick, `, after $DNSSERVER...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From line 2:

```
 $DNSSERVER=get-content env:computername
```

should be:

```
$DNSSERVER = $Env:Computername
```

The error is in this line:

```
$List = get-WmiObject -ComputerName $DNSSERVER -Namespace root\MicrosoftDNS -Class MicrosoftDNS_Zone
```

Make sure that it's on the same line instead of separate lines, It is requesting the class for the gwmi command, but since it is in another line it's not taking it. Because the class does exist [in here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so the issue should be in that particular line.

Another point it is looking for the DNS class so only would work if the windows servers have DNS feature or role installed on it.